# Split sentence into words

Tags: php, text-segmentation

for example i have sentenes like this:

```
$text = "word, word w.d. word!..";
```

I need array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => word
    [1] => word
    [2] => w.d
    [3] => word".
)
```

I am very new for regular expression..

Here is what I tried:

```
function divide_a_sentence_into_words($text){ 
    return preg_split('/(?<=[\s])(?<!f\s)\s+/ix', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY); 
}
```

this

```
$text = "word word, w.d. word!..";
$split = preg_split("/[^\w]*([\s]+[^\w]*|$)/", $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($split);
```

works, but i have second question i want to write list in mu regular exppression 
"w.d" is special case.. for example this words is my list "w.d" , "mr.", "dr."

if i will take text:

$text = "word, dr. word w.d. word!..";

i need array:

```
Array (
  [0] => word
  [1] => dr.
  [2] => word
  [3] => w.d
  [4] => word 
)
```

sorry for bad english...

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: What exactly is a "word"?  How do you define, in English, what a "word" is?  Before you can write a regular expression, you have to be able to describe, in English, the rules that you're trying to implement.

Comment: **Show us what you've tried so far.**  Don't describe it, but edit the question and paste in the actual code.  Then tell us what didn't work.  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Comment: i try:
function divide_a_sentence_into_words($text){
  return preg_split('/(?<=[\s])(?<!f\s)\s+/ix', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
}

Answer (score 8):

Using `preg_split` with a regex of `/[^\w]*([\s]+[^\w]*|$)/` should work fine:

```
<?php
    $text = "word word w.d. word!..";
    $split = preg_split("/[^\w]*([\s]+[^\w]*|$)/", $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    print_r($split);
?>
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/IFaQkbsk)

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => word
    [1] => word
    [2] => w.d
    [3] => word
)
```

Comment: yes this works, but i have second question i want to write list in mu regular exppression 
"w.d" is special case..
fore example this words is my list "w.d" , "mr.", "dr."

if i will take text:

$text = "word, dr. word w.d. word!..";

i need array:

Array
(
    [0] => word
    [1] => dr.
    [2] => word
    [3] => w.d
    [3] => word
)

Answer (score 5):

Use the function explode, that will split the string into an array

```
$words = explode(" ", $text);
```

Comment: It looks like he wants to ignore the periods/punctuation at the ends of words.

Comment: I understand it does not have enough content to reproduce, but the question did not have much information either so it's not that complex

Comment: this gives you last word:
[4] => word!..

and second word will be 
[1] => word,

Comment: Not only is this obviously an incorrect answer, if it actually was the correct answer, then you should have voted to close as a duplicate instead of answering.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
str_word_count ( string $string [, int $format = 0 [, string $charlist ]] )
```

see here http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php
it does exactly what you want. So in your case :

```
$myarray = str_word_count ($text,1);
```

Comment: see the doc, this method also returns each word in an array

Comment: If '.' is included in the $charlist argument, then it will be treated as part of a word; though a preg_split expression would be better because that could distinguish between `.` between characters and a `.` followed by a space

Comment: This answer does not respect the task requirements in the question body.