# how to make every word a link in input or textarea in php

Tags: php

i have this input

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sentence" placeholder="Sentence" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
```

after submission I want it to display the input and make every word a link like

```
<a href="?sentence=<?php echo $row['id']?>"
```

Comment: You could explode on spaces, then build links for every word; or use a regex if you wanted to be specific on what a "word" is.

Comment: Are you using AJAX for form submission?

Comment: im using php. so far i have only display the results

Comment: Look at some other threads on the topic and try building something. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133857/split-sentence-into-words